# Making strings view able in multiple classes

Tags: java, string

I am trying to access a `String` from another class but this `String` is variable.

The `String` is:

```
String username = new String (EnterUsername.getText());
```

Currently it's in the class `loginScreen.java` but I need to access it in another class, `SellingScreen.java`

How do I make this `String` `public` and viewable throughout my classes?

I have now tried using in `LoginScreen.java`:

```
public String GetUsername()
     {
      String username = new String (EnterUsername.getText());
        return username;
     }
```

And to access it in `SellingScreen.java`:

```
 LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
 String Username = loginScreen.GetUsername();
```

I've tested to see if it returns a value with:

```
System.out.println(" hello " + Username);
```

but this returns nothing.

Ive tested within the method with the following but only displays "hello"

```
public String GetUsername()
     {
      String username1 = new String (EnterUsername.getText());
      System.out.println("Hello" + username1);  
      return username1;

     }
```

Comment: @LawrenceAiello I tried your method

Answer (score 1):

I think that it could be static, you can use it between classes:

```
public static String username = new String (EnterUsername.getText());
```

Comment: Or maybe 
public static String getUsername() {
 return EnterUsername.getText();
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method in the class `LoginScreen.java`:

```
public String getUsername() { return username; }
```

Make sure to keep the actual string data member private:

```
private String username;
```

Now in your `main` function in `SellingScreen.java` (or wherever the main class is) you need to instantiate the LoginScreen class and get the string:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LoginScreen loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
    String theUsername = loginScreen.getUsername();
}
```

Comment: I have tried your method but still wont work, can you please look at the edited version?

Comment: It's a little hard for me to debug without seeing the rest of your code. What is `EnterUsername`? Are you sure that works?

Comment: `EnterUsername` is a textField in a netbeans GUI, That works and returns a value. However when i use this in a method, it does not return the value in the method. I updated the code above to check for the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an attribute `private String username;` and a public getter method `public String getUsername () { return username; }`.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a instance of your first class in your second class.

```
MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
```

nameOfClass.object so for here and to access in another class...

```
otherClassVariable = mainClass.username;
```

Or you would have to make the string static. If the variable is static, then there is only one copy of it and you would not need to create an instance of your first class.

```
Static String username = new String (EnterUsername.getText());
x = MainClass.username ;
```